# Can't get fresh length of list Telegram bot API

Tags: global-variables, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have flask telegram bot with pyTelegramBotAPI deployed on Heroku. Need to get fresh lenght of list in the start message. List refreshing every 5 minutes in **gettinglist.py**. Can't find my mistake, please help.

**bot.py**

```
import config
import gettinglist
from gettinglist import getting_list
import telebot
from flask import Flask, request
from threading import Thread

def app_run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=os.environ.get('PORT', 80))

msg_start = """
Lenght of list now: %d
""" % config.LIST_LENGHT

application_thread = Thread(target=app_run)
getting_list_thread = Thread(target=getting_list)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("<MY_BOT_TOKEN>")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start():
    cid = m.chat.id
    bot.send_message(cid, msg_start, parse_mode='html')

@app.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "ok", 200

@app.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url="<HEROKU_APP_URL>")
    return "ok", 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application_thread.start()
    getting_list_thread.start()
```

**gettinglist.py**

```
import config
from time import sleep

LIST_LENGHT = 0
LIST = []

def getting_list():
    while True:
        global LIST
        global LIST_LENGHT

        LIST = [num for num in range(0, 100)]
        config.LIST_LENGHT = len(LIST)

        return LIST
        sleep(300)
```

**config.py**

```
LIST_LENGHT = 0
```

Comment: what is the *list*?

Comment: @anatol, list of random values. It is refreshing every 5 minutes and has a different number of list items. List refreshing in **gettinglist.py** and fresh number of list need to show in start message in **bot.py**.

Comment: so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @anatol, this script shows always **ZERO** in start message. But the list is never empty.

Comment: you have `LIST_LENGHT = 0` in *config.py*, isn't it? and in you bot start message you getting directly`config.LIST_LENGHT`

Comment: @anatol, yes it is, but this variable should changing in **gettinglist.py** and to be access in **bot.py**

Comment: yeah, but I didn't see where `getting_list()` was executed in *bot.py*

Comment: @anatol, i'm start 2 threads. **application_thread** running the flask server and **getting_list_thread** running the getting_list().

Comment: when you set text for start message the lehgth is 0, so you need call lehgth calculation before this

Comment: @anatol, Look at **bot.py**. I'm importing **config.py** firstly than **gettinglist.py**. I think the problem is not this.

Comment: could you try replace *msg_start* declaration after *getting_list_thread*?

Comment: @anatol, I tried it, it did not help. Need some method for storing the value of global variable.

Comment: in any case this is not `telegram` or `telegram-bot` specific question